# Node.js loop through array doesn't show entire objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose

I have found strange behavior of array in Node.js

Googling didn't help. Ofc, it may cause of my fatigue. If so, I am sorry.

So, my model

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    added: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    displayName: String,
    cart: [{
        orderNumber: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        exposition: Object,
        offer: Object,
        state: Number,//1 - Unpaid
    }],
});
```

In controller I am trying to loop through cart array

```
    var cartId = new ObjectId(req.body.id);
    mongoose.model('User').findById(currentUser.userId, function (err, user) {
        var cart = user.cart;
        console.log(cart);
        var expId = -1;
        if (cart) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                var cartItem = cart[i];
                console.log(cartItem);
                if (cartItem._id === cartId) {
                    console.log("SHIT");
                    expId = user.cart.exposition._id;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I didn't find better solution to find embedded cart in user than loop.
So, when I am logging my cart object

```
console.log(cart);
```

I am getting correct object and it works ok, but when I am trying to log

```
console.log(cartItem);
console.log(cart[0]);
```

I am getting only

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JSON.stringify your object before console logging.  Then you should see a string representation of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the default `toString()` for an object. Try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(cartItem));
console.log(JSON.stringify(cart[0]));
```

instead if you want to see the structure of the object.

Comment: I know the structure of my object. I want to compare its id with cartId. So, it doesn't work. I am sure, that ids are equal.

Comment: `===` will always fail then if you're trying to compare two different objects. Have you tried `cartId.equals(cartItem._id)` ?

Comment: Not matter how would I compare object now. For me more important is Why must I use stringify to access my object's structure?

Comment: Because the default `toString()` implementation for `Object` just returns `[object Object]`. If you want it in a human-readable format (i.e., JSON), then you have to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

This problem arises because you are using `findById()`
which returns result inside the array

According to my knowledge, there can be only one user record inside `User` document

**Solution:**
Use `findOne()` which return a single user result, and you can iterate through `user.carts`